# Boilerplate Cache Busting Question

Tags: javascript, css, browser-cache

1) I'm confused about the purpose of setting header expiry dates
for caching css and js files (like how it's done in the 
Boilerplate .htaccess file).

I thought web browsers automatically cache css and js files.
What's the point of setting header expiry dates?

2) Is there a way to NOT use versioning of css and js files and
still have them automatically update when I upload them to a server.
I tried setting a lower expiry date ("access plus 1 week" and "access
plus 0 seconds") and the browser was still displaying the old cached copy
when I uploaded updated css and js files. I'm not 100% sure I did this
correctly, though.

Thanks :)

Comment: ..so thats http://html5boilerplate.com/ you're referring to ?

Comment: Yep :) Damn, I need more characters ^_^

Comment: You should always set headers to tell the browser (or proxy) how you want your content cached (or not) - relying on the browser to guess it for you means it will guess it wrong at least some of the time.  More importantly if you have an image you want to cache for a very long time setting a header is the best way to ensure it gets cached accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Some browsers don't cache things that do not have an expiration date.

2) Try appending a get variable to the end of your URL string to new versions of your website to ignore previous versions cache.  The idea is to transform your urlstring into something like `www.example.com/?v=1` and then when you change that to `www.example.com/?v=2` the browser does not recognize this url so it doesn't use any cached files.  When a user goes back to `www.example.com/?v=2` it will access the cached files for `v2` of your website

Comment: What I was wondering was if there is a way for the browser to get the updated files WITHOUT having to use caching.

Comment: err...without versioning, not caching

Comment: No.  The browser needs to see the file as a new file.  Otherwise it just loads up what it has in the cache.